# Eclipse template or shortcut for clearing a line

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, Ctrl+D can be used to delete a line. After Ctrl+D, the next line replaces the deleted line, and the next next line replaces the next line, ... till the end of the code file.

Now I want to 'clear' a line instead of deleting it via template or shortcut. The cleared line turns blank, and the next line does not replace this cleared line, or the total number of code lines remain the same after clearing it.

Example: after clearing 'System.out.println("b");'

```
System.out.println("a");
System.out.println("b");
System.out.println("c");
```

becomes

```
System.out.println("a");

System.out.println("c");
```

instead of

```
System.out.println("a");
System.out.println("c");
```

How to achieve this via eclipse template or shortcut? An idea is to create an eclipse template composed of 'backspace' or 'delete' characters and then a line break. How to achieve this?

Comment: Does *Delete to the end of a line of text* helps you? Minor inconvenience that you must place cursor at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Exactly what I need